# In jeykll, why latex can't be parsed when I name the post with suffix markdown but it works when with suffix html?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, maruku

I am using the maruku markdown engine in jeykll, and when post a post, I use math code such as:

> \begin{aligned} \dot{x} & = \sigma(y-x) \ \dot{y} & = \rho x - y - xz
> \           \dot{z} & = -\beta z + xy \end{aligned}
>
> $ \dot{x} & = \sigma(y-x) \ \dot{y} & = \rho x - y - xz \
> \dot{z} & = -\beta z + xy $
>
> \( \dot{x} & = \sigma(y-x) \ \dot{y} & = \rho x - y - xz \
> \dot{z} & = -\beta z + xy \)
>
> \[ \dot{x} & = \sigma(y-x) \ \dot{y} & = \rho x - y - xz \
> \dot{z} & = -\beta z + xy \]

if the post name is ended with markdown or md instead of html, only the first latex code can be parsed and transformed to a correct layout.

Why? How should I do so that I could name file with suffix .markdown and hanle the latex correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `` to wrap the original mark could solve the problem, such as:

`\(\Latex\)` or `\[ your equation here \]`